# Get input value using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, forms

i need to get my input value using JavaScript but i get `undefined` only. Here is my code:

```
document.forms[0].elements[0] or
document.forms['form_id']['fieldname']
```

Where is my mistake?

Here is my form:

```
 <form action="registrationHandler.php" onsubmit="return validateRegistrationForm()" method="post" name="reg_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="reg-form">
        <div>
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" required="">
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" required="">
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="email">E-mail</label>
            <input type="text" name="email">
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="telephone">Telephone</label>
            <input type="text" name="telephone">
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="sex">Sex</label>
            <input type="radio" value="male" name="sex">Male
            <input type="radio" value="female" name="sex">Female
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="user_photo">User photo</label>
            <input type="file" name="user_photo">
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="birthDate">Birth Date</label>
            <input type="date" name="birthDate">
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="country">Country</label>
            <input type="text" name="country">
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="info">Info about user</label>
            <textarea name="info"></textarea>
        </div>

        <div>
            <input type="hidden" name="PHPSESSID" value="<?php echo session_id(); ?>">
        </div>

        <div><input type="submit" value="Register"></div>
    </form>
```

Form lies in php file, maybe problem in that? Because when i console log `forms.length` i get zero...

Comment: show the complete code or put it here.. jsfiddle.net

Comment: What exactly is `undefined`? You say you're retrieving `value`, but in the code example there's nothing, which tries to read a value. Please show the relevant real code you have.

Comment: second way give `Cannot read property 'fieldname' of undefined ` error,
`document.forms[0]` give same result

Comment: @excluded_once please include your code :)

Comment: actually that's all code)

Comment: You need to actually get the value: `document.forms[0].elements[0].value`. But if you are getting *undefined* then the first part isn't getting the element.

Comment: Show us the html as well. And where is this javascript called from? Form submit? Button Click? Has your HTML actually got `form` tags?

Comment: Cannot read property 'elements' of undefined

Comment: Please be more accurate. When reading a value, getting `undefined` is totally different from getting an error message which contains a word "undefined". Also, when are you executing this code?

Comment: Your basic code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/phe3617r/, there must be something else you're not telling us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put these DOM object accessing codes into the window.onload event handler,because it need to wait the document loaded before accessing the DOM objects.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try for example:

```
document.forms['reg-form']['email'].value
```

I think you might not are not targeting the right Dom-element with

```
document.forms['form_id']['fieldname']
```

Please look at this jsfiddle-Sample:

http://jsfiddle.net/3gevoyn5/8/

I have two input fields and get the Values with this code, which is then output again:

```
function getValues(){
    var test = document.forms['myform']['firstname'].value + " " +  document.forms['myform']['lastname'].value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = test;
}
```